# What is the subjective inverse of "invite" or "invitation"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns

If you are about to do something and you ask someone to join you, you "invite" (verb) them, or send them an "invitation" (noun). But, in the opposite direction, if they ask to join you, what verb or noun describes their action toward you?

Comment: If someone asks to join you they are in a sense inviting you to do something with them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best word for *to invite oneself* is the verb, *to impose*, or its noun form, *imposition*. While the exact meaning regarding invitation is slightly ambiguous in this usage, it does describe their hindering behavior well. The second definition of *impose* from the Cambridge English Dictionary comes rather close to your desired purpose.

> To cause inconvenience to someone or to try to spend time with them when they do not want you to

Depending on the level of formality, you could also use the colloquial adjective *self-invited*. However, if this is for anything more than an informal exchange, I would strongly encourage the usage of *impose*.

Comment: But I don't think there's any suggestion of them *imposing* themselves in the question, is there? They simply 'ask to join you'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Fair point; I missed that. I'm not sure what the best word would be for non-colloquial non-imposing self-invitation. Of course, *self-invited* is becoming a more commonly accepted word. Perhaps that will find its way into more formalized usage. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

to get invited by/to receive an invitation from

Comment: I believe the question is looking for the opposite of these words, something along the lines of self-invited.

Comment: Yes. The words 'in the opposite direction' are misleading, I think.